# Get "usable" window width in vim script

Tags: vim

[image: get the width of text field in vim]

How do I get the width of 3 (marked with green color in the image) in vim script?

If there is no `signs` column, and there are no other "special columns", I can get it with

`winwidth(0) - (max([len(line('$')), &numberwidth-1]) + 1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think, you should be able to get that width using:

```
:set virtualedit=all
:norm! g$
:echo virtcol('.')
```

Alternatively, you could check, whether a signcolumn is present (e.g. using `redir`)

```
:redir =>a |exe "sil sign place buffer=".bufnr('')|redir end
:let signlist=split(a, '\n')
:let width=winwidth(0) - ((&number||&relativenumber) ? &numberwidth : 0) - &foldcolumn - (len(signlist) > 1 ? 2 : 0)
```

Comment: I'm gonna go with the second one, the first solution will have visual effect, something you don't want in a script. I will not accept your answer, for now, (but thanks :-) to see if someone can come up with something like `editareawidth()`.

Comment: There is no such function and it is not needed.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I would not say it is not needed. It is not needed if all you want buffers for is editing some text, but not if you want to have some interface there. Though just sane scripting interface for signs would be enough.

Comment: @ZyX As an author of several plugins that use the sign feature, I agree, one needs a better VimL integration. I even wrote patches for that. But not for having a editareawidth function

Comment: Its possible to have `&numberwidth` non-zero while no number column is being displayed.  In the second snippet, one should probably replace `&numberwidth` with something like `((&l:number || &l:relativenumber) ? &numberwidth : 0)`.

Comment: `&numberwidth` is defined as the minimum number of columns to use for the line number. This means that this is  useful only if line number < 1000. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @NotanID you might want to accept the answer. thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `len(signs)` be `1` if the sign column is not present and `2` if it is? that would make the part `len(signlist) > 1 ? 2 : 0`. At least that's the only thing that works for me. I'm running neovim-nightly v0.5.0-508-gc37d9fa3d, with ale. Redir returns `['--- Signs ---', 'Signs for file.py:']` when the signcolumn is present and only `['--- Signs ---']` when it isn't. On a side note, if/when I start using gitgutter with ale, how would I get the width of signcolumn if it increases beyond 2?

Comment: YEs, indeed you are correct here. Note, that nowadays one can use `sign_getplaced()` to get the signs placed in a buffer. One does not need the redir anymore. I don't understand the comment about *signcolumn increasing beyond 2*, unless neovim changed that behaviour, the signcolumn can never have more than 2 columns

Comment: How to just get the current signs width?

Comment: @Rainning if signcolumn is enabled, it is always 2 (at least for Vim, Neovim changed this behaviour a bit)

Answer (score 4):

My [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) has a `ingo#window#dimensions#NetWindowWidth()` function for that.

Answer (score 4):

Answering because I can't comment yet:

Christian's answer gives the wrong result in the case that the actual number of lines in the file exceeds `&numberwidth` (because `&numberwidth` is just a minimum, as kshenoy pointed out).  The fix is pretty simple, though, just take the `max()` of `&numberwidth` and the number of digits in the last line in the buffer (plus one to account for the padding vim adds):

```
redir =>a | exe "silent sign place buffer=".bufnr('') | redir end
let signlist = split(a, '\n')
let lineno_cols = max([&numberwidth, strlen(line('$')) + 1])
return winwidth(0)
            \ - &foldcolumn
            \ - ((&number || &relativenumber) ? lineno_cols : 0)
            \ - (len(signlist) > 2 ? 2 : 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Kale's answer corrected one corner case where the number of lines is exceeding what `&numberwidth` can display. Here I fix another corner case where the `signcolumn` option is not set to `auto`

```
function! BufWidth()
  let width = winwidth(0)
  let numberwidth = max([&numberwidth, strlen(line('$'))+1])
  let numwidth = (&number || &relativenumber)? numberwidth : 0
  let foldwidth = &foldcolumn

  if &signcolumn == 'yes'
    let signwidth = 2
  elseif &signcolumn == 'auto'
    let signs = execute(printf('sign place buffer=%d', bufnr('')))
    let signs = split(signs, "\n")
    let signwidth = len(signs)>2? 2: 0
  else
    let signwidth = 0
  endif
  return width - numwidth - foldwidth - signwidth
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers take into account the following points -

- Plugins use sign-groups (if available), so simply running `exe "silent sign place buffer=".bufnr('')` does not show the sign's placed in the plugin's group
- Neovim has support for variable signcolumn width

So this is the answer that finally set the ball rolling for me. Of course it is influenced by all of the above answers -

```
function! BufferWidth()
    let width = winwidth(0)
    let numberwidth = max([&numberwidth, strlen(line('$')) + 1])
    let numwidth = (&number || &relativenumber) ? numberwidth : 0
    let foldwidth = &foldcolumn

    if &signcolumn == 'yes'
        let signwidth = 2
    elseif &signcolumn =~ 'yes'
        let signwidth = &signcolumn
        let signwidth = split(signwidth, ':')[1]
        let signwidth *= 2  " each signcolumn is 2-char wide
    elseif &signcolumn == 'auto'
        let supports_sign_groups = has('nvim-0.4.2') || has('patch-8.1.614')
        let signlist = execute(printf('sign place ' . (supports_sign_groups ? 'group=* ' : '') . 'buffer=%d', bufnr('')))
        let signlist = split(signlist, "\n")
        let signwidth = len(signlist) > 2 ? 2 : 0
    elseif &signcolumn =~ 'auto'
        let signwidth = 0
        if len(sign_getplaced(bufnr(),{'group':'*'})[0].signs)
            let signwidth = 0
            for l:sign in sign_getplaced(bufnr(),{'group':'*'})[0].signs
                let lnum = l:sign.lnum
                let signs = len(sign_getplaced(bufnr(),{'group':'*', 'lnum':lnum})[0].signs)
                let signwidth = (signs > signwidth ? signs : signwidth)
            endfor
        endif
        let signwidth *= 2   " each signcolumn is 2-char wide
    else
        let signwidth = 0
    endif

    return width - numwidth - foldwidth - signwidth
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [Vim 8.2.3627](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/cdf5fdb2948ecdd24c6a1e27ed33dfa847c2b3e4), [`getwininfo()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#getwininfo%28%29)'s output has a `textoff` containing the

> number of columns occupied by any `'foldcolumn'`, `'signcolumn'` and line number in front of the text

therefore subtracting that to the `width` entry, e.g. computing

```
getwininfo(win_getid()).width - getwininfo(win_getid()).textoff
```

should give the desired result.

---

Before `textoff` was available, it seems to me that the followinig computation does cut it:

```
let textoff = max([&numberwidth, (&number ? len(line('$')) + 1 : (&relativenumber ? winfo.height + 1 : 0))])
    \ + &foldcolumn
    \ + (empty(sign_getplaced(bufname(), {'group': '*'})[0].signs) ? 0 : 2)
```

---

I made use of both solutions in [this plugin of mine](https://github.com/Aster89/vim-softwrap) for showing soft-wrapped lines.