# Colorcolumn and text wrapping at the same time in Vim

Tags: vim, word-wrap

I am setting `colorcolumn` in Vim, on the 90th column, but at the same time I would like to maintain text wrapping functionality.

Therefore, in order to maintain the coloured column on the wrapped lines, and have no breaks, I have to put in my `.vimrc` something like:

```
let col_no=90
if ((longest_line_size / 90) >= 2)
  for i in range(2, (longest_line_size / 90))
    let col_no=col_no . "," . ((90*i) + (&columns - 91))
  endfor
endif
execute 'set colorcolumn=' . col_no
```

The problem is that when I resize the window (or the buffer), the coloured column on the wrapped lines is not aligned. A solution would be to re-run the function when the buffer is resized.

Is this possible? Any other solutions/suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a function every time the window size changes using the following autocommand

```
augroup Resize
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimResized * :call YourFunctionName<cr>
augroup END
```

Add that to your vimrc file. To use it with your code you will need to wrap the code up in a function.

```
function YourFunctionName
  #your code goes here
endfunction
```

Note that the function name must begin with a capital letter.

Comment: Thank you, this is right. In order to complete the algorithm I also need to know the number of columns in the current buffer (&columns is the number of columns in the whole window). Do you know how this can be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315925/get-usable-window-width-in-vim-script should answer your question. Also, if you liked my answer I'd appreciate an upvote. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much! I would love to upvote, but my reputation does not allow me to do that yet. I will come back when I collect enough points.

Comment: No problem; that makes sense.

Comment: I reached the necessary reputation and upvoted your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: aww, y'all should stay in touch